# make don't build file even if dependency is updated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

this is my make file:-

```
VER = Debug
CC = g++

OBJECTFIELS = main.o Time.o

main: $(OBJECTFIELS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTFIELS) -o $@

$(OBJECTFILES): Time_.h

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTFIELS) main
```

every time I change the Time_.h file, nothing happens:-

```
$ make
make: 'main' is up to date.
$ touch Time_.h 
$ make
make: 'main' is up to date.
```

other files compile when changed :-

```
$ touch main.o
$ make
g++ main.o Time.o -o main
```

please I am complete noob. Please tell why is this happening

Comment: Typo: Your variable is called `OBJECTFIELS` but you're trying to use it as `OBJECTFILES`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks !!! I am so stupid and mad

Answer (score -3):

You need to generate new .o files in your rule for Time_.h.

```
$(OBJECTFILES): Time_.h
```

This says make should run a command whenever Time_.h is updated, and that the command will generate both main.o and Time.o. But no command is given!

```
Time.o: Time_.h
        $(CC) Time_.cpp -o Time.o
```

This is the kind of rule you want. Whenever Time_.h changes, we run $(CC) Time_.cpp -o Time.o, which will generate Time.o. Now if some other rule depends on Time.o, make will know that this command can be used to create Time.o, but that it only needs to be run if Time_.h changed since the last time make was run.

I'm specifying "Time.o" explicitly, since your source filenames don't seem to exactly match the object files you're expecting. (Time.o vs Time_.o)

Comment: but the manual says that I can use this sysntax:- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Combine-By-Prerequisite.html#Combine-By-Prerequisite

Comment: I would avoid that style for now... see here for the standard makefile format: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Example.html#Rule-Example

Comment: None of this is necessary.  Make knows how to build object files from source files and it's perfectly reasonable, and not to be avoided, to use the built in rules if they work for you.  The original makefile in the question is completely correct and needs no modification, except for the typo in the variable name noted in the comments above.

Comment: Actually the rule given in this example is not correct because it's missing the source file as a prerequisite.

Comment: Also _the command will generate both main.o and Time.o_ that's not what that rule says.

Comment: Just to clarify: `$(OBJECTFILES): Time_.h` says that the object files (`Time.o` and `main.o`) depend on `Time.h`.   Because there is no recipe defined, means that it is just a dependency declaration, and it will pick up the recipes from somewhere else -- i.e. the default pattern rule for `%.o`.